# CSS3 Multiple Transitions of the Same Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-animation

I am trying to make a dropdown effect for one of my background images.  I was able to do it using css3 but it's not complete.

The effect is supposed to be a curtain that drops down then sort of bounces back up a little.  The problem with css3 is that I don't know how to do to transitions on the same property because the last one overrides the previous ones.

Here's my code:

```
ul#nav li a {
  /* ADDS THE DROPDOWN CURTAIN TO THE LINKS BUT HIDDEN OFF SCREEN */
  background: url(images/drape2.png) 0px -149px no-repeat;
  /* CSS3 transitions */         
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;         
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;         
} 

ul#nav li a:hover {            
  /* Action to do when user hovers over links */                          
  background-position: 0px 0px; /* make drape appear, POOF! */             
  background-position: 0px -10px; /* make drape appear, POOF! */             
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825509/css3-chain-animations

Comment: What's the difference between an animation and a transition?

Comment: Ha, didn't even realise ! Well, just discovered something good here. http://www.webkit.org/blog/324/css-animation-2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `cubic-bezier` like this:

`cubic-bezier(0, 0.35, .5, 1.3)`

You can make an animation go backwards—or bounce a little.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZB69m/) (Only works in Firefox)

[Source](http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/animation-css-transitions-jquery-easy/)

Edit: I also made you a [Webkit only option](http://jsfiddle.net/ZB69m/2/), I don't know how compatible these two techniques are. It may also work in Firefox with the `-moz` browser prefixes, but I haven't tested it. This one uses keyframe animation as opposed to transitions.

Answer (score 9):

You'll want to chain them with commas instead of a new line

For instance:

```
background-color 500ms linear, color 500ms linear;
```

Comment: I don't see where I would use that.

Comment: That's how you do multiple transitions on the same property.