# Regarding Your solution for multiple css3 transitions

Tags: css, transition

Thanks in advance I was reading your point on [CSS3 Multiple Transitions of the Same Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275893/css3-multiple-transitions-of-the-same-element/21979431#21979431) and added my code below as it doesn't seem to work for me but wondering if it is because you cannot target scale without calling all?

Code:

```
.link-amazon a {
    background:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47292400/amazon1.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:140px;
    position:relative;
    text-indent:-3000px;
    width:258px;
   -moz-transform:scale(1);
   -webkit-transform:scale(1);
   -o-transform:scale(1);
   -ms-transform:scale(1);
    transform:scale(1);
   -webkit-transition: scale .7s ease-in-out,background-position 0 linear;
   -moz-transition: scale .7s ease-in-out,background-position 0 linear;
   -ms-transition: scale .7s ease-in-out,background-position 0 linear;
   -o-transition: scale .7s ease-in-out,background-position 0 linear;
    transition: scale .7s ease-in-out,background-position 0 linear;
}

.link-amazon a:hover {
    background-position:0 -140px;
   -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
   -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
   -o-transform:scale(1.1);
   -ms-transform:scale(1.1);
    transform:scale(1.1);
    opacity:1;
}
```

have also tried this....

```
.link-amazon a {
  background:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47292400/amazon1.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
  display:block;
  float:left;
  height:140px;
  position:relative;
  text-indent:-3000px;
  width:258px;
  -moz-transform:scale(1);
  -webkit-transform:scale(1);
  -o-transform:scale(1);
  -ms-transform:scale(1);
  transform:scale(1);
  -webkit-transition:transform .7s ease-in-out,background-position 0 linear;
  -moz-transition:transform .7s ease-in-out,background-position 0 linear;
  -ms-transition:transform .7s ease-in-out,background-position 0 linear;
  -o-transition:transform .7s ease-in-out,background-position 0 linear;
  transition:transform .7s ease-in-out,background-position 0 linear;
}
```

where scale is switched for transform but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You have to transition the property, not the value of the property (that is, transform and not scale)

Comment: tried that like...   below

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this

```
-moz-transform:scale(1);
```

for firefox, then you should use this

```
-moz-transition: -moz-transform .7s ease-in-out,background-position 0 linear;
```

If you are using this

```
-webkit-transform:scale(1);
```

for webkit, you should use

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s ease-in-out,background-position 0 linear;
```

and so on ...

Comment: If you see my above I have followed that but it still doesn't work, can you see my code in the answer above? I am still getting familiar with stackoverflow, can you not put code in comments?