# two keyframe that implement first after another

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

i have a div that it needs two effect that must implement one after another.i use delay() (in jquery) between two animation but it has not required result.indeed i wanna chain two keyframe.What is the proposed solution?
thank a lot

Comment: but i use css3  for animate and use jquery for select element and bind event

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's animate() has a built in callback function:

```
$("#elementID").animate({top: 0}, 1000, function() {
    $(this).animate({top: 1000}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Webkit has an animation delay property, but that is only Webkit. I'd highly recommend using jQuery for your animations.

Check out this Stack Overflow question: 
**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825509/css3-chain-animations**

jQuery transit is also a nice plugin for using CSS3 animations, while using jQuery syntax. 
**http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/**