# Queue css transition

Tags: jquery, css, transition, animate.css

I have a problem that don't let me sleep.

Assume that I have these divs:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="sixteen columns">
        <div class="dark animated fadeOutRight"><img src="images/dark.gif"></div>
        <h2 class="motto">aspettaci...</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

animated with animate.css (but i think that any animation is good as example).

I want to create a sequence of divs that transit in the page.
for example.

> div1 -> fade out then
>    after n seconds div2 -> slide in then
>    div2 -> slide out then div3 comes and STOP...

I try with delay but its a mess and div2 is always visible on the page. I don't really know how to do this. Maybe I have to move all divs out of the pages, or I can do this in much simply way with jQuery?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Some jQuery code to start with would be nice. It's easier to hunt down some error or make some adjustments than to provide code from scratch

Comment: It would be good to Google for "jQuery How to chain animations :stackoverflow" and have some sleep

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 Chain Animations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825509/css3-chain-animations)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-webkit-animation-duration` and `-webkit-animation-delay` for simulate effect.

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/4bWvQ/**

HTML :

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

CSS :

```
#div1{
    // Some Stuff 
    -webkit-animation-name:move;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#div2{
    // Some Stuff 
    -webkit-animation-name:move;
    -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#div3{
    // Some Stuff 
    -webkit-animation-name:move;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move{
    from{ // Some Stuff }
    to{ // Some Stuff  }
}
```

Think to add all prefix for browsers compatibility

Comment: Note that the other prefixes and unprefixed version of this code are also necessary to be cross browser

Comment: Yes you are right, but this example just shows the principle to achieve this effect has

Comment: the problem is that the three objects aren't visible in the windows toghether... Div2 must be hidden and come visible after div1 goes fade out...but i try to use your advice....thanks a lot

Comment: Why you don't use `opacity` css property during the animation for achieve what you want

Comment: You can also use percent in keyframes and make a more complicated animation - https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Answer (score -1):

i understand the u looking for trigger animation one after another ... and one of the easy way to do that is through ".animate()" method.

```
$( "#div1" ).animate({
   opacity: 0
   }, 5000, function() {
   // 1st Animation complete.
   // start 2nd animation.
       $( "#div2" ).animate({
          opacity: 0
          }, 5000
       );
});
```

hope this is helpful. 
And if u can explain more clearly what exactly u trying to achieve, that would help

Comment: jQuery's animate performs terribly FYI

Comment: @ZachSaucier how gud it will performs, its on u... as u have customize your animation by yourself. so if u have an example please share.

Comment: It in fact does *not* depend on how the developer uses it. The actually jQuery implementation of `.animate` is slow when compared to vanilla javascript, CSS, GSAP, Velocity.js, etc.

Comment: ohh u taking in terms of efficiency.. ya that's true. but its not that terrible to boycott it totally and not to use it for small things.