# Apply multiple translates at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, transform

I'm wondering how I can have the following two animations happen on an element simultaneously:

```css
@keyframes BackgroundSnowfall{
    from    {transform: translate(0px, 0px);}
    to      {transform: translate(0px, 936px);} 
}
```

```css
@keyframes shuffle{
    0%      {transform: translate(0px);}
    33%     {transform: translate(20px);}
    66%     {transform: translate(-20px)}
    100%    {transform: translate(0px)}
}
```

Both the animations are being run with a very wide difference in their duration (about a 55 second gap), so I'd rather not have to do the math and create a long single animation keyframes to incorporate them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825509/css3-chain-animations), you might be able to **chain** the two keyframe animations.

**EDIT**

[Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986129/play-multiple-css-animations-at-the-same-time) that shows how to wrap an image in a `<div>` and apply one transform to the `<div>` wrapper and a second transform to the `<img>`.

Here's an example:

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  animation: vertical 10s infinite;
}

img {
  animation: horizontal 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes vertical{
    from    {transform: translate(0px, 0px);}
    to      {transform: translate(0px, 936px);} 
}

@keyframes horizontal{
    0%      {transform: translate(0px);}
    33%     {transform: translate(20px);}
    66%     {transform: translate(-20px)}
    100%    {transform: translate(0px)}
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAIAAAD/gAIDAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAADbSURBVHhe7dAxEQAgDAAxhHTEvzM8YKG/5y4Kct5clmQFsgJZgaxAViArkBXICmQFsgJZgaxAViArkBXICmQFsgJZgaxAViArkBXICmQFsgJZgaxAViArkBXICmQFsgJZgaxAViArkBXICmQFsgJZgaxAViArkBXICmQFsgJZgaxAViArkBXICmQFsgJZgaxAViArkBXICmQFsgJZgaxAViArkBXICmQFsgJZgaxAViArkBXICmQFsgJZgaxAViArkBXICmQFsgJZgaxAViArkBXICmQFsgJZa3M/KCjwdMHWsEkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" /></div>
```

Comment: I would like to use transforms, though, because they have a higher processing power than left positioning. The issue is my shuffle transform is overriding my BackgroundSnowfall transform.

Comment: @JordanCarter I edited the answer - maybe this version will work for you?

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.